# Changing the color of existing titlebar and icons

Tags: tkinter, titlebar

I am developing a desktop application in which I want to change the color of the title bar in tkinter. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBiGN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter doesn't provide the ability to change the color of the titlebar.